# Regex to dynamically ignore some parts of a given path

Tags: java, regex

Consider that I have the following string which is a "complete path":

```
/A/B/C/D/E
```

And there is also the "simplified path" string:

```
/A/B/E
```

I have a situation where some parts of the string can be omitted and still be represent the full path. I know this is strange, but I can't change it.

Basically for this case, I need a regex to ignore the last two paths before the current path (dynamically as I have no specific information of them), to confirm that these two strings have a correlation.

The only thing I could came up with was:

- Take the current path (`([^\/]+$)`) from both strings and compare.
- Check in Java if the complete string contains the simplified one.

But I think there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Do they point to the same file or directory?

Comment: It is a path, but not directory. I am using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) concept here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

- Search string:
  `[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+$)`
- Replace string: `\1`

[Check it here](https://regex101.com/r/pT9zW2/1)

Comment: Great! I understand what it's doing here but can you explain a bit more on how it's doing?

Comment: Of course, we are searching for 3 sections with / separating them, in order to do that we are searching for every character besides the separator, then we capture only the last one, and replacing the entire found sequence with the last part.

Answer (score 1):

If both path point to the same file/directory then you could make use of the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class. 
It has a method [Files#isSameFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path)) to which you pass two Path instances and it would check if both files are pointing to the same file at your directory. This simple line would check if `A/B/E/` and `/A/B/C/D/E` are actually the same directory.

```
System.out.println(Files.isSameFile(Paths.get("/A/B/C/D/E"), Paths.get("/A/B/E")));
```

Comment: Thank you. But notice that I always the word "path"used because it is indeed a path, but I never said "directory" because actually, it's not. It is an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Comment: I didn't mention that because I thought there will be no difference, as I still have two simple Strings at that point. My problem is that for some complicated reason, `/A/B/E` actually refers to `/A/B/C/D/E` and I must know that.

Comment: Still give you a +1 for your try :)